# Metric Spaces Proof

Tags: general-topology

> Let p be a prime number, and d: $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to [0, +\infty)$ be a function defined by
>   $d_p(x, y) = p^{−\max(m∈N : p^m|x−y)}$
>   .
>   Prove that $d_p$ is a metric on $\mathbb{Z}$ and that $d_p(x, y) \leq \max(d_p(x, z), d_p(z, y))$ for every $x, y, z \in \Bbb{Z}$

What I tried:
I tried to use triangle inequality condition and assume that $m_{xy} = -\log_p(d(x,z))\leq m_{yz}$ and then set up an inequality but then I got stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the p-adic norm.  (It brings back memories). To prove it is a metric you have to prove the triangle inequality.

This statement, once you prove it, *is* how you prove the triangle inequality.

If $d_p(x,y) \le \max(d_p(x,z),d_p(z,y))$ then $d_p(x,y) = \text { either } d_p(x,z) \text { or } d_p(z,y) \le d_p(x,z) + d_p(z,y)$.

Thus the triangle inequality follows.  It's actually *stronger* than the triangle equality.  It has been noted that in this metric space "every triangle is isoceles".

To prove it is a metric space

i) for every $(n,m) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ the $d_p(m,n) \ge 0$ with $d_p(m,n) = 0 \iff m = n$.

ii) $d_p(m,n) = d(n,m)$

These are straightforward and:

iii)$d_p(x,y) \le \max(d_p(x,z),d_p(z,y))$ (and therefore $d_p(x,y)\le d_p(x,z) + d_p(z,y)$

Hint: Let $p^k | x - z$ and $p^l | z - y$ and, wolog $m \ge l$.  Show that $p^l | (x - z)+(z - y) = x - y$.

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $d(x,y)=1/p^a$ and $d(y,z)=1/p^b\leq d(x,y).$ Then $p^b\geq p^a.$ We have $$(1)... x-y\equiv 0\pmod {p^a}.$$  $$(2)... y-z\equiv 0\pmod {p^b}. $$ But since $p^b\geq p^a$ we have $$(3)... y-z\equiv 0\pmod {p^a}.$$ From (1)  and (3) we have $$x-z=(x-y)+(y-z)\equiv 0\pmod {p^a}.$$ $$Hence... d(x,z)\leq 1/p^a=d(x,y)=\max (d(x,y),d(y,z)).$$ The  case  $d(y,z) >d(x,y)$ is handled similarly.